# python OpenCV detect all pixels with pre defined value

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am working on a project and need to identify all pixels in a screen with a specific color, and produce a binary array with the output.

I would like to know the most efficient way to do this, thanks.

I have attempted to use the `cv2.inRange` but failed. here was the code :

```py
import cv2
import numpy
from mss.windows import MSS as mss

sct = mss()

monitor_1 = sct.monitors[1]

color=numpy.array((0, 206, 224),dtype=numpy.uint8)

while True :
    screen = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor_1))

    mask = cv2.inRange(screen,color, color) # modify your thresholds
    inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
    arrow = cv2.bitwise_and(screen, inv_mask)

    cv2.imshow('arrow', arrow)
```

Comment: Try [cv2.InRange()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)

Comment: I tried that but kept getting an error and had no clue how to fix it (`The lower boundary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar in function 'cv::inRange'`)

Comment: Please post the code you are testing and your input image.

Comment: heres my image https://i.imgur.com/GkWfZdA.png

Comment: Try defining the color threshold as an array: `color  = numpy.array([0, 206, 224])`. Your image should also be an `8-bit uint` matrix.

Comment: please can you explain? on line 9 color is already an array with `dtype=numpy.uint8`. do you mean the mask?

Comment: Try a range of colors. You are probably off by just a bit. So a lower color and an upper color. Subtract say 20 from each of your values for the lower and add 20 to each of your values for the upper.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can use [`inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) and you may want to use some tolerance on your BGR value.

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("GkWfZdA.png")
yellow = im[130,130,:].astype(int)
mask = cv2.inRange(im, yellow-50, yellow+50)
```

[image]

(`astype(int)` is needed to make sure that `0 - 10 == -10` and not `246`, `inRange` automatically clamps values to a valid range)

Comment: I'm trying your solution on a different color and cannot find out how to change what value it detects. can you please update the answer with more explanation?

Comment: the color (`yellow`) was taken from the center pixel in my answer (`im[130,130,:]`), but you can also specify it directly as BGR value (e.g. `(0,0,255)` for red)